# SPARQL filter regex and union

Tags: sparql, ontology

My ontology has 2 classes: `food` `foodSource`.
I want to get the data for the class `food` with 2 kinds of `foodSource` using the SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?food ?foodSource ?foodSource2
WHERE {
  {
    ?foodSource mpasi:data_memerlukanBahan ?memerlukanBahan.
    ?food ?memerlukanBahan ?value.
    FILTER  regex(str(?foodSource),"carrot")
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?foodSource2 mpasi:data_memerlukanBahan ?memerlukanBahan.
    ?food ?memerlukanBahan ?value.
    FILTER  regex(str(?foodSource2),"tomato")
  }
} 
order by ?food
```

I get the correct result. But then I want to avoid some food sources. So, how do  can I get food that doesn't have a food source?  For example, I have 3 kinds of food:

- kedelai porridge
- apple crumble
- tomato soup

Then i want food without apple inside it. So, naturally i just get kedelai porridge and tomato soup.
Can i get it using !regex?

```
FILTER  (!regex(str(?foodSource),"apple")).
```

Comment: Regex supports union and negation which is probably more efficient than writing it via SPARQL union and MINUS.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a first step is to refactor your `UNION` statement.  The first two triple patterns are the same for both `UNION` graph statements, so move those outside of your `UNION` statement.  Then you're left with just the two `FILTER` statements, which can be re-written with an `||` expression:

```
SELECT ?food ?foodSource ?foodSource2
WHERE {
  ?foodSource mpasi:data_memerlukanBahan ?memerlukanBahan.
  ?food ?memerlukanBahan ?value.
  FILTER (regex(str(?foodSource),"carrot") || regex(str(?foodSource2),"apple"))
}
```

Perhaps better, as @AKSW suggests, is to perform the `or` in the regex itself:

```
FILTER regex(str(?foodSource),"carrot|apple")
```

Since `FILTER` in SPARQL is a positive filter - it states what to let through - then "carrot" and "apple" are the only possible solutions. "potato" can't get through the filter.

However if you wanted to find everything but "potato", then you have a couple of negation choices:

```
FILTER (!regex(str(?foodSource),"potato"))
```

or via regex negation:

```
FILTER regex(str(?foodSource),"[^potato]")
```

Comment: `"[^potato"]` has some unbalanced brackets/quotation marks.  But even so,  I *think* that that doesn't do what you want; I think that `[^potato]` just matches a single character that isn't p, o, t, or a.

Comment: Fixed the typo.  The regex is correct.  Inside a character class `^` negates the string.

Comment: I know out negates, but `[abc]` matches one character from a b and c; doesn't `[^abc]` match one character that's not a b or c?

Comment: After some more checking, `[^...]` doesn't behave the way you're describing. E.g., `values ?food { "potato" "potatoes" "oat" "pot" } filter regex(?food, "[^potato]")` produces only `potatoes`, because only it  has a character *not* in {p,o,t,a}.  SPARQL [regex](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex) is based on XPath **matches**; a few links in leads to [negative character group](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#nt-negCharGroup).  `[^potato]` is equivalent to `[^pota]` and matches a character that's not in the set {p,o,t,a}.

Comment: It actually leads to a kind of sneaky bug, because `[^word]` *will* always fail to match `word` (when `word` is the entire string), so it initially looks like it works.  But it would also fail to match `wood`, `door`, `or`, `do`, `ow`, etc., because they also lack characters not in the set.