# filter sparql for two instance from the same class

Tags: regex, filter, sparql

Hello i want to ask you how to get some data with more than one condition from the same class. I have two kind of class `?food` and`?foodSource`. Then i want to get food with food source "potato" and "carrot" in one recipe. So how can i get the data, because currently i use this :

```sql
SELECT ?food ?foodSource1 ?foodSource2
WHERE {

  ?foodSource1 mpasi:data_memerlukanBahan ?memerlukanBahan.
  ?food ?memerlukanBahan ?value.

  ?foodSource2 mpasi:data_memerlukanBahan ?memerlukanBahan.
  ?food ?memerlukanBahan ?value.

  filter regex (str(?foodSource1),"potato").
  filter regex (str(?foodSource2),"carrot").
}
order by ?food
```

But it seems it was wrong.... Thanks before

Comment: This seems very similar to your earlier question,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227051/sparql-filter-regex-and-union. Did the answers there not work for you? It might be better to update that question if these are sufficiently similar.

Comment: Looks like you still do not fully understand SPARQL. I mean, there is no connection between triple pattern 1 and 3 and 2 and 4 are obviously exactly the same.